# My flat leaf parsley has stunted growth and pale red leaves. What could be wrong?

Tags: diagnosis, herbs, parsley

My flat leaf parsley is not looking very healthy; the growth seems stunted, and the leaves are starting to turn a pale red. What should I do to revive it?

[image: Parsley in a pot]

Answer (score 7):

Parsley forms a tap root; it looks like the soil in your pot isn't very deep, so the root might not be developing properly.  You might be able to **carefully** lift the plant with root ball intact, put some more soil underneath it, then replace the plant.  This would give it the root some more space to develop.

Another possibility -- since parsley is a relative of the carrot -- is that it's being attacked by [Carrot fly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrot_fly).  Prevention is your best defense here, see the [Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrot_fly#Control) section of the Wikipedia page.

Comment: Good tip, I've already done as you suggested. I noticed the soil was covered in a fine white power, could that be something to do with Carrot fly?

Comment: @Dan: I don't think so.  If you search for information on Carrot flies, they say that the eggs are laid in the soil near the root, and the larvae burrow into the root.  I often find that potting compost will form a white layer on top shortly after I first use it, which I attribute (though quite possibly wrongly) to fungi growing on the organic matter in the compost.